# eclipse jsp: move .tag common imports to shared file?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, eclipse-wtp

I have moved multiple common `<%@ tag import=... %>`s from several `.tag` files to a shared `.tag` (or '.jsp') file and included that shared file in all other tag files.

It works in tomcat/jetty but eclipse fails at recognizing them and reports compile error on imported classes. Instead eclipse recognize them when I change them to `<%@ page import=... %>` but then tomcat/jetty fails.

```
<!-- import.tag -->
<%@ tag  import="java.util.List"%><!-- eclipse: compilation error on `List list;` "List can not be resolved to a type", jetty/tomcat: ok -->
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%><!-- eclipse: ok, tomcat/jetty: page directive cannot be used in a tag file -->

<!-- another.tag file -->
<%@ include file="import.tag" %>
<% List list; %>
```

Is this an eclipse bug? Is there any solution?

Edit:
I'm using Indigo Service Release 1, Build id 20110916-0149, Java EE IDE for Web Developers / Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Which version are you using?  It sounds like a bug, but without version numbers, it's impossible to say.

Comment: Not sure why it complained about List, but you should have seen a warning about the page directive.  Is this a Maven project?

Comment: I have this problem in a simple default web project as well as maven projects.

Comment: Can you attach the simple default web project to a bug report?

Comment: @nitind Finally I reported it! https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=387529

Comment: @nitind has there been any progress with this issue? am I really the only one with this problem?!